# How to prevent id field from increasing when using bulkCreate or upsert in Sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, mariadb, sequelize.js

The issue arises when I use `bulkCreate` or `upsert` in **Sequelize** to create a record if it not exist in database and otherwise update it. Basically, they serve my purpose successfully but there is one thing that makes me concerned is that for each record update `bulkCreate` and `upsert` will increase the value of id field (primary key) therefore if a new one record inserted, it will have an id value much greater than previous records. So how can I prevent the id field from increasing each time they update the records?

This is the records when I use `bulkCreate` and `upsert`.These are queries I use: 
`model.bulkCreate(data, { updateOnDuplicate: [] };` 
`model.upsert(data);`

[image]

This is the records I want them to be.

[image]

I use MariaDB. Thank you for your attention!

Comment: What's the definition of `id` in DB?

Comment: It's the primary key with type of number and autogenerated value

Comment: I could guess that. I just wanted to look at its SQL definition as is